# Show only VIEWS in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, view, show

How can i see only VIEWS in SQLite.

**.tables** command list both views as well as tables. I want to see only VIEWS and not tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'view';
```

In order to fine-tune it:

```
.headers on
select * from sqlite_master;
```

you will know what columns are available there.